# Solving system of PDEs with gradient

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, linear-pde

I have the following system of PDEs:

$\partial_x q = -c(b_1 \partial_x u + b_2 \partial_y u)$

$\partial_y q = -c(\partial_y u + b_2 \partial_x u)$

where $b_1,b_2,c$ are constants, with $c$ positive. In more compact form:

$\nabla q = -c B \nabla u$

where $B = \left( \begin{matrix} b_1 & b_2 \\ b_2 &1\end{matrix} \right)$.

The matrix $B$ and the function $u$ are given. How can we find $q$?

Comment: write $U(x) = u(c B x)$, then the PDE is $\nabla (q-U) = 0$, so $q-U$ is constant

Comment: Thanks! Are you saying that $\nabla u (c B x) = c B \nabla u (x)$?

Comment: No, its $\nabla (u(cBx)) = cB\nabla u(cBx)$. which means I misspoke.... sorry

Comment: no worries! Thanks for trying to help anyway

Answer (score 2):

Lets suppose that $q$ exists. Your right hand side is completely known so you can just integrate. Note that for any $\mathbf x = (x,y)$,
$$ \partial_t (q(t\mathbf x)) = \nabla q(t\mathbf x) \cdot \mathbf x$$
so that (assuming some initial condition $q(\mathbf 0)$ is given)
$$q(\mathbf x) = q(\mathbf 0) + \int_0^1 \nabla q(t\mathbf x) \cdot \mathbf x  \ dt$$
i.e. $$ q(\mathbf x) = q(\mathbf 0) - c\int_0^1 (B\nabla u(t\mathbf x))\cdot \mathbf x \ dt $$

If your domain doesn't contain every straight line from $\mathbf 0$ to any point, a [variant of the above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem) will work (since the integral of a gradient does not depend on the path of integration, only the endpoints.)

---

(edit) OP has clarified that the domain is $\mathbb R^2$. On a simply connected set, a vector field $F$ is a gradient iff it is curl free, so for existence, we will need to assume 
$$\operatorname{curl} (B \nabla u) = b_2 \partial^2_x u + \partial_{xy} u - b_1 \partial_{xy} u - b_2 \partial_y^2 u = 0.$$ Here, we verify that $\tilde q(\mathbf x) :=q(\mathbf 0) + \int_0^1 F(t\mathbf x)^T \mathbf x dt$, $q(\mathbf 0)$ arbitrary, is indeed a solution to $\nabla q = F$, if $\operatorname{curl}F = \partial_x F_2 - \partial_y F_1 = 0$. Equivalently, the jacobian $\nabla F$ is symmetric.

On the one hand,product and chain rules for differentiating in $\mathbf x$ give $$\partial_i (F(t\mathbf x)_j \mathbf x_j) = \partial_k F_j(t\mathbf x) \partial_i(t\mathbf x)_k\mathbf x_j + F(t\mathbf x)_j \delta_{ij} = t \underbrace{\partial_i F_j(t\mathbf x) \mathbf x_j}_{=(\nabla F(t\mathbf x)^T\mathbf x)_i }+ F_i(t\mathbf x), $$
so that
$$ \nabla \tilde q = \int_0^1 t\nabla F(t\mathbf x)^T\mathbf x + F(t\mathbf x) dt.$$

On the other hand, carefully differentiating a specially chosen function in $t$,
$$\partial_t(tF(t\mathbf x)_i) = F(t\mathbf x)_i + t\partial_t (F(t\mathbf x)_i) = F(t\mathbf x)_i + t\partial_k F_i(t\mathbf x) \partial_t (t\mathbf x_k) =  F(t\mathbf x)_i + t\underbrace{\partial_k F_i(t\mathbf x) x_k}_{=(\nabla F(t\mathbf x) \mathbf x)_i} $$
i.e.
$$ \partial_t (tF(t\mathbf x)) = F(t\mathbf x)+t\nabla F(t\mathbf x) \mathbf x$$
which is the integrand of $\nabla \tilde q$, since $\nabla F$ is symmetric; the result now follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, but I don't quite see how you go from the first equation to the second one...

Comment: @FredG., that's the fundamental theorem of calculus. $\int_0^1 G(t) dt = G(1) - G(0)$

Comment: @FredG. sorry, in the previous comment the fundamental theorem of calculus is of course $\int_0^1 G'(t) dt = G(1) - G(0)$, note the missing $'$ in the prior comment...hopefully it wasn't too confusing

Comment: Yes, sure! At the beginning I was not understanding how you were using it, but it is clear now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again...I was thinking about when q actually exists. I tested your solution with $u(x,y) = (x-y)^3 + y^3$ and it seems to me there is something wrong...is it because of some domain issues? I suspect the problem is in the matrix B. If I take it to be the identity, then your solution works perfectly

Comment: @FredG. I don't think that B would be a problem, what B did you try? Also what is your domain?

Comment: I kept B generic, with $b_1$ and $b_2$ as above. I am not sure about the domain, though...I would expect $q$ to have the same domain as $u$, that is $R^2$. Regularity should not be an issue....

Comment: @FredG. I was mistaken, you need to make an assumption that $B\nabla u$ is curl free. I will update the answer for this

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is great. I just would have one small question. In light of how you defined $Curl F$, shouldn't we write $Curl (B \nabla u) = b_2 \partial^2_x u + \partial_{xy} u - b_1 \partial_{xy} u - b_2 \partial_y^2 u$. It is not a big deal...just to check that everything is correct

Comment: @FredG. whoops, yes thats right

Comment: Ok, no worries! Thank you very much! I sincerely appreciate all your help and time :)

Comment: @FredG. you're welcome! Sorry for stumbling around, I should know better :)

Comment: Probably I should know better too ahaha